# Django : 'DeleteQuery' object has no attribute 'add'

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a user authentication form in django. Once I login into the form with the super-user credentials, I am having this error : 'DeleteQuery' object has no attribute 'add'
I am using login, REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, logout methods from the django.contrib.auth module.

This is my Traceback :

```
File "/home/ramana/enorgo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/ramana/enorgo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ramana/enorgo/enorgo/utils/view_functions.py" in wrapper
  23.             output = func(request, *args, **kw)
File "/home/ramana/enorgo/enorgo/apps/base/views.py" in login
  55.             login_user(request, form.get_user())
File "/home/ramana/enorgo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in login
  83.         request.session.cycle_key()
File "/home/ramana/enorgo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py" in cycle_key
  279.         self.delete(key)
File "/home/ramana/enorgo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py" in delete
  75.             Session.objects.get(session_key=session_key).delete()
File "/home/ramana/enorgo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in delete
  695.         collector.delete()
File "/home/ramana/enorgo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py" in delete
  277.                 query.delete_batch(pk_list, self.using)
File "/home/ramana/enorgo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py" in delete_batch
  47.             where.add((Constraint(None, field.column, field), 'in',

Exception Type: AttributeError at /login/
Exception Value: 'DeleteQuery' object has no attribute 'add'
```

Comment: Unless you provide the relevant code, it's impossible for anyone to answer this question. Can you edit your question to include your form class and the corresponding view?

Comment: @xjtian : I have added the traceback. Can you please check now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this problem was solved when I shifted to a different database. If someone could explain why this happened, that would be great.